# Unable to start preference screen from NavigationDrawerFragmet

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, preferences

I have created NavigationDrawer activity from File>New>Android Application Project. I choose Navigation Drawer Activity and all goes well till I need to start Preference screen. Application crash.
What I have so far:

Main Activity:

```
...
case R.id.bSettings:
Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Preferences.class);
StartActivity(settingsActivity);
break;
...
```

Preferences.java:

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Note that I don't want inline preference, but preference like new activity.

09-22 13:57:57.125: W/EGL_genymotion(2120): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-22 13:57:57.125: E/OpenGLRenderer(2120): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
09-22 13:57:57.137: E/OpenGLRenderer(2120): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
09-22 13:57:57.137: D/OpenGLRenderer(2120): Enabling debug mode 0
09-22 13:58:00.245: D/AndroidRuntime(2120): Shutting down VM
09-22 13:58:00.249: W/dalvikvm(2120): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4ba8648)
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {ba.arnes.aconverter/ag.android.aconvert.Preferences}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at ag.android.aconvert.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:545)
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-22 13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 13:58:01.841: I/Process(2120): Sending signal. PID: 2120 SIG: 9

Comment: Please provide a Logcat, we don't know the problem without description of the actual problem.

Comment: What is the exception stack trace that you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the Activity declaration in AndroidManifest.xml.

As it says:

`13:58:00.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2120): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {ba.arnes.aconverter/ag.android.aconvert.Preferences}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml`

**Unable to find Preferences**

EDIT:

Looks like you are trying to launch `Activity` and your Preferences class is `Fragment`. So basically you need an Activity class where in layout you have placeholder for fragment (e.g. your **Preferences class**).

```
public class PrefenecesActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle s) {
        super.onCreate(s);
        setContentView(R.layout.preferences);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.holder, new PreferencesFrag());
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public static class PreferencesFrag extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }
}
```

And the layout could look like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Not to forget add the activity to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".PrefenecesActivity" />
```

THEN you can use your code:

```
case R.id.bSettings:
Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PrefenecesActivity.class);
startActivity(settingsActivity);
break;
```

Comment: Yes but I think it is not going to work because you are trying to launch `Activity` and your Prefeneces class is `Fragment`

Comment: I edited the answer, let me know if that cleared things for you

Answer (score 0):

vilpe89: Thank you man! You have it right with a little change...

AndroidManifest.xml should be:

```
<activity android:name="add.full.name.PrefenecesActivity" />
```

instead of:

```
<activity android:name=".PrefenecesActivity" />
```